# Trouble type-checking Aeson decoding into generic types

Tags: json, haskell, typeclass, aeson

This is my first attempt at JSON deserialising with Aeson. I'm having trouble to type-check a generic decoding function for all my domain data types, even though a corresponding decoding function for a single concrete type does work.

Here is the polymorphic function:

```
import qualified RIO.ByteString.Lazy           as BL
import qualified Data.Aeson                    as J
import qualified Path.Posix                    as P

loadDomainData :: J.FromJSON dData => FC.AbsFilePath -> IO dData
loadDomainData filePath = do
    fileContents <- readFileBinary $ P.toFilePath filePath
    let
        decData :: Maybe dData
        decData = J.decode $ BL.fromStrict fileContents
    case decData of
        Just d -> return d
        Nothing -> throwString ("Could not decode data file " <> P.toFilePath filePath)
```

After initial failures, I inserted a type annotation for the target type of the decoder, but to no avail. If I try to compile it, the following type-check error results:

```
    • Could not deduce (J.FromJSON dData1)
        arising from a use of ‘J.decode’
      from the context: J.FromJSON dData
        bound by the type signature for:
                   loadDomainData :: forall dData.
                                     J.FromJSON dData =>
                                     FC.AbsFilePath -> IO dData
        at src/Persistence/File/ParticipantRepository.hs:44:1-64
      Possible fix:
        add (J.FromJSON dData1) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            decData :: forall dData1. Maybe dData1
    • In the expression: J.decode $ BL.fromStrict fileContents
[..]
```

What am I missing? Thanks four any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need the type annotation at all.  Does it not compile fine without it?

What you are missing is that variables in a type signature in a `let` or `where` clause are not scoped within the type signature of the containing function.  So, the type variable `dData` in the signature for `loadDomainData` is completely unrelated to the `dData` in the signature for `decData`.  GHC is complaining that the type in `decData` has no `J.FromJSON` instance because the type signature says it doesn't have one.  You can add it:

```
decData :: J.FromJSON dData => Maybe dData
```

or you can turn on the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension and modify the type signature for the containing function to mark the `dData` variable as scoped:

```
loadDomainData :: forall dData. J.FromJSON dData => FilePath -> IO dData
```

while keeping the same `decData` declaration as before (no `forall` and no `constraint`):

```
decData :: Maybe dData
```

or, as mentioned above, you can remove the type signature for `decData` entirely.  So, all three of the following should work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

-- Add constraint to `decData` signature
loadDomainData :: J.FromJSON dData => FC.AbsFilePath -> IO dData
loadDomainData filePath = do
    fileContents <- readFileBinary $ P.toFilePath filePath
    let
        decData :: J.FromJSON dData => Maybe dData
        decData = J.decode $ BL.fromStrict fileContents
    case decData of
        Just d -> return d
        Nothing -> throwString ("Could not decode data file " <> P.toFilePath filePath)

-- Use ScopedTypeVariables
loadDomainData :: forall dData. J.FromJSON dData => FC.AbsFilePath -> IO dData
loadDomainData filePath = do
    fileContents <- readFileBinary $ P.toFilePath filePath
    let
        decData :: Maybe dData
        decData = J.decode $ BL.fromStrict fileContents
    case decData of
        Just d -> return d
        Nothing -> throwString ("Could not decode data file " <> P.toFilePath filePath)

-- No `decData` signature
loadDomainData :: J.FromJSON dData => FC.AbsFilePath -> IO dData
loadDomainData filePath = do
    fileContents <- readFileBinary $ P.toFilePath filePath
    let
        decData = J.decode $ BL.fromStrict fileContents
    case decData of
        Just d -> return d
        Nothing -> throwString ("Could not decode data file " <> P.toFilePath filePath)
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I was indeed unaware that the signature of the function type does not carry over to the actual function definition.